# How to automaticlly create an InputField, when a a position is clicked on a picture?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display a highlighted circle when the user double clicks on a certain part of an image(which should be erasable if clicket wrong). If the wanted position is clicked i want to create an "ID" and next to it a simple Inputfield.
The Inputfields should be in a countainer/box which is scrollable.
How can I achieve this ?

here is a edited pic as example for what i hope to achieve:

[image: screenshot of the request]
till now i only did the ground work like bulding the header, footer and sidebar

```css
#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  clear: both;
}

#menue-right {
  width: 300px;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: black;
  float: right
}

#content {
  width: 700px;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

#content-center {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: darkorange;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 125px
}

#wundbild {
  height: 400px
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1 style="color: white; text-align: center;padding-top: 25px;">Wundposition ermitteln</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="menue-right">
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content-center">
      <img id="wundbild" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3CDS.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the double click can occur anywhere in the image ? Does the new `input` field has a relation with where the click happened ?

Comment: @ths yes if the user clicks on a random place it shoud appear on the right side a new entry with an Id and a textfield for a comment like 

id: 1 | " headache" <-- and if the user clicked wrong the entry should be deletable for example through a button (X)

the clicked area should be highlitet with a circle